# sum() in postgresql is returning individual rather than aggregated values

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, datetime, sum

I'm having trouble getting a `sum()` function working in my database. I am querying table `purchases` for the `store_id` (retrieved from table `stores`), `month`(+year) of purchase (stored as a `timestamp` without time zone specified), and the `sum` of the `total` sales income by month. The problem is that no aggregation occurs, so that each sale's total is being reported as the monthly total of sales for a given store. I suppose I'm not using `sum()' correctly, but I haven't found a solution. Suggestions and advice appreciated.

```
SELECT --month of purchase, total sales
    purchases.store_id AS store_id, 
    TO_CHAR(timestamp, 'Month'||'YYYY') AS month,
    sum(total) AS total_sales
    FROM purchases
    GROUP BY store_id, timestamp, purchases.total
    ORDER BY month, store_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grouping by `timestamp` while you want to group by month.

Consider:

```
SELECT
    store_id,
    date_trunc('month', timestamp) AS month,
    sum(total) AS total_sales
FROM purchases
GROUP BY store_id, date_trunc('month', timestamp)
ORDER BY month, store_id;
```

This gives you `month` as a date truncated to the first day of the month: I find this more meaningful that a formatted string, but you can change that back to the original `to_char()` expression if you prefer.

Note that PostgreSQL also supports positional arguments in the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clause, which lets you write:

```
SELECT
    store_id,
    date_trunc('month', timestamp) AS month,
    sum(total) AS total_sales
FROM purchases
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 2, 1;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I also learned that `date_trunc` can be nested in the `to_char` function, which works nicely as a back-end, front-end pair where the first decides aggregation and organizing, the second takes care of the presentation.